# how to make a website with images in background

Tags: jquery, css, html, user-experience

[link to the target site](https://www.freecharge.in/)

I want to make a site similar to this. similarity with respect to the design of website not an actual recharge website. But I don't have a lot of time to concentrate on UX so I want to find a template to use, so that I can actually concentrate on the business logic. I do not know what I am supposed to search for to find templates like this, I mean the search terms. So please help me.

I actually tried lot of things but it is not working.

Comment: The general term to describe this kind of effect is 'Parallax' which refers to the elements scrolling somewhat independently of the page, giving a 3d layered effect.

Comment: can you help me in finding similar templates online,or any site

Comment: That's not really the intended purpose of stackoverflow, though you should be able to find what you're looking for if you search for 'Parallax templates' or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a tutorial](http://codyhouse.co/gem/alternate-fixed-scroll-backgrounds/) on how to make a similar background type (with download of source)

This uses CSS to create a fixed and scroll backgrounds. using the CSS background-attachment property set on fixed.

It has a [demo as well](http://codyhouse.co/demo/alternate-fixed-scroll-background/index.html) to see if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: *template (not tutorial)
But it will tutor you in its application I am sure :)

Comment: No problem!
Glad I could help point you in the correct direction! :)